# {!pickVal == objRecord.{v.kanbanPicklistField}} Can any give a work around?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

`{!pickVal == objRecord.{v.kanbanPicklistField}}`

is there any workaround to use this type of expression is possible to use in lightning?

Answer (score 0):

A likelier syntax would be:

```
{!pickVal == objRecord[v.kanbanPicklistField]}
```

but only integer indexes are supported inside the `[]`.

In my experience you have to do this work in JavaScript i.e. define an `aura:attribute` to hold the result and then in the init or in a change handler:

```
var o = component.get('v.objRecord');
var p = component.get('v.kanbanPicklistField');
component.set('v.result', o[p]);
```

and in the component:

```
{!v.pickVal == v.result}
```